# Show/Hide after selecting value from <select>

Tags: jquery, json

This is a basic jquery show/hide.

```
$(function() {
    $('.schools').hide();
    $('#district').change(function(){
        $('.schools').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

that will show high, middle and elementary schools from a district after selected. I want to do it in a **json** format, I guess is easy for maintenance. Bear with me please, I'm just a designer playing around with jquery. **[This is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/hNZqE/)**. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do in json format?

Comment: Yes, sorry the question is not clear.

Comment: we are still not sure what you need help with? What do you actually want to do? Load the three school dropdown list from a database?

Comment: @Daveo  I want to do it in json.